# Check if any number in a Ruby array is greater than or equal to 100

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given a Ruby array of `[5, 20, 13, 100]`, how can check if any single one of those items is `>= 100`?

Ultimately wanting it to return `true` or `false`.

Seems I could do something like `arr.select { |num| num >= 100 }` and count them, but seems there'd be a more succinct method or it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `[5, 20, 13, 100].any?{|x| x >= 100 }`.

Comment: Or `[...].sort.last >= 100`. C-;

Comment: Great answer, but IMHO bad comment. Why sorting when you have only to transverse the array once? BTW upvoting for being faster than me :)

Comment: Because Ruby is like Perl (and unlike Python) - there's always more ways to do it.

Comment: `arr.find { |x| x >= 100 }` and `arr.index { |x| x >= 100 }` are alternatives to `any?` in that they too quit when a value or index is found and return a truthy or `nil` value, but `any?` reads best. Aside: `sort` makes no sense, so why bring it up?

Comment: And since this is Ruby:
`class Array
 def does_contain_any_value_greater_than(n)
  !self.delete_if{|a| a<n}.empty?
 end
end
p [5, 20, 13, 100].does_contain_any_value_greater_than 100`

Comment: `[...].max >= 100`

Comment: Or `arr.any?(100..Float::INFINITY)`

Comment: Yup. I forgot about the `.max` - that might be the cleanest solution. But remember only the latest Rubies support `.any?(PATTERN)`.

Answer (score 0):

From a basic point of view you can do with your Array `ary`:

a nice old plain `for`:

```
ret = false
for i in 0...(ary.size)
  if ary[i] >= 100
    ret = true
    break
  end
end
```

or you can use a `while`

```
ret = false
i = 0
while not ret or i < ary.size
  ret = ary[i] >= 100
  i += 1
end
```

or you can use an `each` method on the array:

```
ret = false
ary.each do |el|
  ret = true if el >= 100
end
```

or you can use `any?` like in @Philip answer

or you can use the `max` method, as cleverly suggested by @sagar-pandya (this solution is extremely nice, but requires to traverse the whole array):

```
ary.max >= 100
```

or you can `map` your array on a newer array of boolean (but this requires two loops over two arrays, thus it is not as efficient as other solutions), and then `inject` the result in a new variable with the result:

```
bol = ary.map { |el| el >= 100 }
ret = bol.inject { |s, el| s or el }
```

or you can use directly `inject` (but this time you have to set initial conditions):

```
ret = ary.inject(false) { |s, el| s or (el >= 100) }
```

Chose your weapon :). But if you want to do it right think about (given your specific task):

- using a method that traverse the array only once;
- using a method that stops when it has found a `true` condition.

Comment: I don't see any value in presenting inferior (boolean) methods. It only weakens your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment, can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Sometimes there is one approach to a problem that is clearly best. In such cases there is no point in mentioning inferior methods as well as the preferred one. Other times (as here) there are two or more approaches that could be used that are similar in efficiency and readability. They might all be presented, but again, it makes no sense to present clearly inferior approaches as well. As I say, answers are weakened (imo) by including inferior approaches, which often (as here) are too numerous to count.

Comment: Uh ok, now I understand. Actually the `map + inject` is there for a didactic only purpose and to introduce the last `inject`, that I consider a little to much to show directly. Or at least, this is what I have to do with students in order to make them understand `inject`...

Comment: Ah, you teach Ruby! I can see the value of stepping through different ways of attacking the problem in a classroom setting, starting with the easiest to understand then working towards the Ruby-like ones, but I don't think most SO members are looking for that in answers. They prefer answers that merely suggest how the problem should be solved.

Comment: I teached Ruby during my Phd, and it also happened that I answered on SO to one of my students question... and I never lost the attitude... But you are completely right :)